# Tm4c nested uart interrupts- does each com finishes it's run before the next one executed?

Tags: interrupt, uart, interrupt-handling

Board: Tiva™ C Series TM4C1294

EK-TM4C1294XL

my program is listening to 2 uarts ports(uart  3 and 7)

I encounter of problem that im loosing some bytes received and im suspecting that this issue relate to the uarts interrupts.

i understand that uarts have nested interrupts but does both of them are serial?

for example: im inside uart 3 interrupt function and then while uart 3 didnt finish the interrupt(just copy their bytes to buffer) uart 7 interrupts arrives, does the system moves to uart 7 or it will first finish uart 3 and then moves to the uart 7?

currently im suffering from error bytes something like 45-400 bytes for file that his size in 12 Mbytes

im suspecting the above issue cause this issues

p.s if only 1 uart is sending data i have binary same files on both host and pc

Thanks

Idan

Answer (score 0):

Depends on interrupt priorities of UARTx. UART3 would relinquish control to UART7 if UART7 priority is higher. Fact that single UART works successfully in copying file on your target & PC, but fails for 45+ bytes in 12Mb file when two UARTs in operation, this would need excerpts of code implementation to analyze. Just in case are you copying same single PC-file through two different UARTs, then file locking mechanism needs to be taken care of OR you can try two duplicate copies of files on PC for each UART to isolate the issue